# Real Models representaed by a multivariate polynomial

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

What are some real Models (from physics, chemistry, biology, finance..) that can be repreeneted as  multivariate polynomials?

I have already tried the   formual of the voltage accross a resistor (V=RI  voltage= resistance * current), but  I am still searching for other examples.
In fact I am using such  models represented by  multivariate  polynomials to apply a method for   error analysis.
May be this is a broad question, but I am not able to make it more tighter! 
Can some one help me with some suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Econometrics uses them by the shed load.

Comment: They are everywhere. In CAD models in engineering for example and anything else geometric. Optical transformations are application or substitution of multivariate polynomials so also when you calculate how the geometric objects look under various circumstances.

Comment: @mathreadler I know they are every where, but here I am asking if some one can help me and provide me with one of such examples.